# sending email with excel as attachment in c# from datatable

Tags: c#, excel, email, datatable, console-application

I have a datatable. I want to send the content of the datatable as excel and send email as attachment. I tried below code but it is sending expty excel file.

First I am converting datatable to stream object and passing the stream to the sendemail method with other mail parameters.

```
 private static Stream DataTableToStream(System.Data.DataTable table)
        {
            const string semiColon = ";";

            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);

            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                sw.Write(column.ColumnName);
                sw.Write(semiColon);
            }
            sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    sw.Write(row[i].ToString().Replace(semiColon, string.Empty));
                    sw.Write(semiColon);
                }
                sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            }
            return ms;
        }
```

below is the sendmail code

```
 private const string ExcelContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        private static bool SendMail(MailAddress from, string to, string[] CCAddress, String strSubject, String strBody, Attachment attachment, Stream tableStream)
        {
            try
            {
                const string attchmentName = "Weekly Vendor Report.xlsx";
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Host = "mail.lamrc.com";

                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                message.From = from;
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Subject = strSubject;
                message.Body = strBody;
                message.To.Add(to);

                message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(tableStream, attchmentName, ExcelContentType));
.......

}
```

Comment: Quick suggestion here, and maybe not to helpful, but have you tried closing/disposing the StreamWriter (or putting it in a using block)? It may not be flushing its contents to the Stream otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) library for convert data table to excel and convert it to attachment.

```
    public static Attachment GetAttachment(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(outputStream))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet facilityWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("sheetName");
            facilityWorksheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);

            package.Save();
        }

        outputStream.Position = 0;
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment(outputStream, "sample.xlsx", "application/vnd.ms-excel");

        retutn attachment;
    }
```

Comment: Hello,This give:Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Attachment'

Comment: are referring from this System.Net.Mail?